# Bad request 400. How should jQuery Ajax data serialize() or json look like?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a form via jquery ajax. I have this:

**JS:**

```
$('#form-pm').on('submit',function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = $('#form-pm').serialize();
        var ajaxRequest =
        $.ajax({
            url: //my valid url,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            type: 'post',
            data: formData    
        });

        ajaxRequest.done(function(data) { console.log(data); });
        ajaxRequest.fail(function(jqXHR) { alert('You are fail. ' + jqXHR); });

    });
```

**UPDATE:**
*JS looks like this now:*

```
var formData = $('#form-pm').serialize();

        var ajaxRequest =
        $.ajax({
            url: admin_ajax.ajax_url,
            type: 'post',
            data: formData

        });

        ajaxRequest.done(function(data) { console.log(data); });
        ajaxRequest.fail(function(jqXHR) { alert('You are fail. ' + jqXHR); });
        e.preventDefault();
```

400 Bad Request is gone, but my function send_message is receiving blank parameters. According to error.log, it's `send_message('',NULL,NULL)`

**PHP:**

```
function send_message($projectid, $userid, $message) {
    //do stuff
}

<form id="form-pm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <textarea name="message" rows=3 id="project-message"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send message">

    <input id="userid" type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $userid; ?>">
    <input id="projectid" type="hidden" name="projectid" value="<?php echo $projectid; ?>">
    <input id="userid" type="hidden" name="action" value="send_message">

</form>
```

I keep getting POST 400 Bad Request. I know it's `data` that is causing trouble. How does post expect `data` to look like?

Comment: Look @Rollor .. `ajax` is step by step check .. first of all the connection between js and php file *just use `url` and `type` in ajax and echo out anything in php and see the returned data*.. 2nd: the **data** sends from js to php *add `data` to ajax then echo the `data` out in php and see the returned data*.. 3rd: the returned data from php to js *if its `json` then add `dataType`* .. let us know about this checks and what is working and in which step this error happen

Comment: Does your "valid url" directly reference the `send_message` function, or does that function receive the data and pass it on to `send_message`?

Comment: it receives the data and passes it to send_message. So far, now, I get send_message(' ', NULL, NULL) according to my error.log with my updated code (see orig post)

Comment: I think you need to remove the .serialize  from var formData = $('#form-pm').serialize();, you might not be getting parameter values in the send_message() function